# How can I find out what is causing vim to interpret python files?

Tags: python, vim

After many years, I'm finally cleaning up my .vimrc and digging into how the settings really, really work.  I spent a lot of the day trimming cruft and reading help files.

Now I'm down to a pretty minimal .vimrc that I'm pretty comfortable with -- and I believe I understand what each thing in it does (lots of commenting).  I'll include my .vimrc at the bottom of this question.

My problem is, I am working in Python (for the first time) and somehow vim has a bunch of settings (I don't like) for it--seemingly built-in.  How can I either:

1. Figure out what is causing those settings and turn it off
2. Get it to give me a nice, blank slate for python files so I can select what settings I want?

Notes:  I deleted my .viminfo file (after backing it up) to get everything clean.

When I open a python file and type `:set`, here is what I get:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  autoindent          helplang=en         modified            scroll=38           smartindent         textwidth=76
  comments=b:#,fb:-   hlsearch            number              scrolloff=5         softtabstop=4       ttyfast
  expandtab           incsearch           relativenumber      shiftwidth=4        suffixesadd=.py     ttymouse=sgr
  filetype=python     keywordprg=pydoc    ruler               showmatch           syntax=python       wildignore=*.pyc
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,!^F,o,O,e
  commentstring=# %s
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  include=^\s*\(from\|import\)
  includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\.','/','g')
  indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)
  indentkeys=0{,0},:,!^F,o,O,e,<:>,=elif,=except
  omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
  printoptions=paper:letter
      runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/vundle,~/.vim/bundle/tabular,~/.vim/bundle/vim-    es6,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/
share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after,~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/,~/.vim/bundle/vundle/after,~/.vim/bundle/tabular/after,~/.vim/bundle/vim-es6/after
```

Notice that `shiftwidth=4` and `softtabstop=4`, for example.

If I open a *blank* file, here's the `:set` I get:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  autoindent          number              shiftwidth=2        ttyfast
  expandtab           relativenumber      showmatch           ttymouse=sgr
  helplang=en         ruler               smartindent
  hlsearch            scroll=38           tabstop=2
  incsearch           scrolloff=5         textwidth=76
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  printoptions=paper:letter

runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/vundle,~/.vim/bundle/tabular,~/.vim/bundle/vim-es6,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after,~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/,~/.vim/bundle/vundle/after,~/.vim/bundle/tabular/after,~/.vim/bundle/vim-es6/after
suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
```

That is what I would expect to get (notice `shiftwidth=2`, for example.  Here's my (rather short) .vimrc:

```
$ cat .vimrc
" Turn on line numbering
set number

" Turn on relative numbers
set relativenumber

" Show the leader key
set showcmd

" Set the <leader> to space.
let mapleader = " "

" Always use a numberwidth minimum of 6
set numberwidth=6


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" Tabbing & Indenting
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" Set the width of a single 'shift'.  This is what occurs when using the >
" or < keys.
set shiftwidth=2

" Set the size of a tab.
set tabstop=2

" Expand tabs to spaces.
set expandtab

" Copy the current line's indent to the next line when starting a new line.
set autoindent

" Use 'smart' indenting for C-style languages.  When this is on, autoindent
" should also be on.
set smartindent

" Lets us use <leader>gg to re-indent the file and return to our current
" location.
map <leader>gg gg=Gu<C-r>


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" Informatics 
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" Show an indicator of where you are in the file.
set ruler


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" Navigation
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" Make it more convenient to jump up or down a page.
map <leader>j <PageDown>
map <leader>k <PageUp>
" Make it more convenient to go to the beginning or end of the file.
map <leader>jj :$<Enter>
map <leader>kk :1<Enter>

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" Aesthetics
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Syntax highlighting
syntax on

" By default, use the "distinguished" color scheme.
colorscheme distinguished

set scrolloff=5

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" Specific highlight rules

highlight Todo none

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" Search 
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" Highlight matches as-you-search
set showmatch

" Turn on incremental search
set incsearch

"""""""""""""""""
""" Highlighting 

" Show all search results highlighted
set hlsearch

" Clears search highlighting by just hitting a return. 
" The <BS> clears the command line. 
" (From Zdenek Sekera on the vim list.) 
" I added the final <cr> to restore the standard behaviour of 
" <cr> to go to the next line 
nnoremap <CR> :nohlsearch<CR>/<BS><CR> 

""" Highlighting 
"""""""""""""""""



"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" Line Structure
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" Set the line length for breaking text
set textwidth=76

" Set this expression to control the way in which lines break.
" set formatexpr <expression>

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" File-level adjustments
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" Turn off swap files.
noswapfile

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" Plugins & Tools
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

" Turn on plugins
filetype plugin on

" Stuff for the Tabular.vim plugin
map ,t :Tab /=<CR>
"command -nargs=1 T1 Tabular /^[^<args>]*\zs[<args>]/l1r0

"""
" Vundle config
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off                   " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
call vundle#begin()
" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required! 
Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'

" Tabular
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'

" JavaScript ES6 plugin
Plugin 'isRuslan/vim-es6'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on     " required!

" The JSONTidy command to format JSON.
command JSONTidy %!python -m json.tool
```

So ... where are the custom settings for python files coming from?

By the way, I checked my .vimrc directory and there are no `indent`, `syntax`, or `color` files for python.

Why is `shiftwidth` 4 for python files?  And where did my `tabstop=2` go (for example)?

Comment: `:set ft=python`

Comment: shiftwidth 4 i believe is because it is common python formatting to use 4 spaces as indent for higher order.

Comment: @liliscent Thanks; but where are those settings found and how can I get them to be LOWER priority than what's in my .vimrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `:verbose set optionname?` will tell you the current value of `optionname` and where it was set.
2. The default Python settings are defined in:

   ```
   $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim
   ```

   Note that they follow Python's "standard" so changing any of that may or may not cause problems down the line (with linters, for example).
3. To override those default settings, create your own Python ftplugin at:

   ```
   ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
   ```

   and add the desired options:

   ```
   setlocal shiftwidth=2
   setlocal tabstop=2
   ```

   As the name implies, that script is sourced *after* the built-in one, which makes it the right place for overriding built-in filetype-specific settings and adding your own.

Comment: Thank you!  The :verbose set optionname? was key missing information.  I was able to tell exactly what I needed to know from that.  The 'setlocal' helps as well.  I read the python style guide (I didn't know there was one), and it looks like everything I want is either a standard or an acceptable alternative (except for the 2-spaces-per-tab thing).

Answer (score 0):

Vim ships with several filetype plugins.  I think the one that's causing your issue is this: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim

You could try removing the file.  Or just find the options that you don't like, and `:let g:OPTION_NAME = 0`.  There's also some discussion on overriding ftplugins here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6658/how-to-override-a-ftplugin#6659.